# BIOS error temps: Sometimes jumps 30 degrees with no explanation

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, temperature

Firstly I apologize for my English.

I have a rather curious problem, I have a B450m board with a Ryzen 5500, update the BIOS to be able to use the 5000 series processors.

Basically the BIOS sets a
temperature of 63 degrees sporadically for a few seconds. For example, it can be at 36 degrees and it goes up to 63 for no reason, always the same value, no higher, no lower.

I can be doing nothing and normal temperatures, but suddenly it will go up to 63, the same if I am playing.

When I play I usually get to 57 degrees and then it goes up to 63 and back down again. I changed thermal paste and checked to see if there was good contact but there was no change.

I did some stress tests, and when it exceeds 63 degrees (70+ to be exact) there is no problem and it does not return to 63. The cpu temperature (tctl/t die) is normal and does not present the phenomenon, only in the bios and in the "Cpu" section derived from the board in hwinfo.

The BIOS is updated to the latest version, and updated every time I can in the hope that the error will be solved but there has been no change. The most annoying thing was the fans, but I made a curve based on exceeding 63 degrees to avoid discomfort.

Likewise, I am worried that this could damage my CPU or the motherboard itself. It should be noted that I have no performance problems. CoreTemp shows normal temperatures, same with afterburner while playing (probably because the temperature values ​​are not taken from the motherboard).

[image: Hwinfo CPU temp in the motherboard section]

Comment: You or a professional use an infra temperature sensor (I use an ExTech) and make a physical measurement of the temperature. Otherwise you will likely go in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is an issue with the correct **reporting** of temperature, rather than that the temperature actually changed. The reasoning behind that is:

- Temperature does not change instantly (unless perhaps in superfluid helium ;-).
- The reading is always shown as *exactly* 63°C, not a bit above or below.
- It appears you state it abruptly goes back to another temperature, on occasion, after reporting 63°C.

What could cause this? Here are just a few possibilities:

- A flaw in the temp reporting firmware, or in the ACPI layer.
- A flaw in timing, so that on a system query of the temperature, a default value is posted when the query fails.
- A flaw in software used to read out the temp, e.g., running queries so frequently that an accurate reading cannot be returned.

Should you be concerned? Probably **not**. Actually, one is more likely to run into issues reapplying thermal compound, since the physical stress can break solder joints or leave voids in the glop. Since you've already done this successfully, however, that's not an issue. Why worry (as [Alfred E. Neuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_E._Neuman) states)?

- Your PC apparently is operating well, and has not given any actual indication of overheating, unless you mean by "The most annoying thing was the fans," that the fans *do* speed up when the temp indicates 63°C.
- Many sources, such as [Avast!](https://www.avast.com/c-how-to-check-cpu-temperature), state that up to 80°C is acceptable, and 65°C is *well* within the acceptable continual operating range.
- The firmware will throttle back the CPU if there *is* overheating.

This is somewhat like an issue I had, in which my automobile's temperature gauge jumped from cool to pinned at max! It needed not a replacement of water pump, expensive in time and money, thankfully, just the temperature sender unit.